# UITouch for UItableview?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitouch

I want to calculate touch location of tableview evenif we scroll it as we do in normal UIView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate touch on selected cell and convert it to table view coordinates. X coordinate will the same as cell, but Y = `Y+indexPath.row*cell.height`.

See also UIView `convertPoint` method.

Comment: ,how Y+indexPath.row*cell.height will be correct after scrolling tableview?

Comment: Y is y-coord in tapped cell. For example 14. You tap tableView at 15'th row. So, 15*44+14 is required value.

Answer (score 0):

If your table view doesn't have more content than the screen size (perhaps static) you can disable the scrolling of the tableView like below

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

If there is more content you can use the,

```
hitTest: withEvent:
```

technique in your UIView subclass.

The actual method is

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

You should use this method in a UIView subclass.

Comment: how can i do it without disabling scrolling and with more content than screen size?